# In Tyepscript, how do I set it to ECMAScript 5?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to compile some typescript code, & get this compiler error:

```
 Accessors are only available when targeting ECMAScript 5 and higher.
```

I thought I had done this by setting my target in the tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true, 
    "esModuleInterop": true
    }
}
```

Comment: That should work, how are you running the compiler ? maybe the `tsconfig.json` is not picked up

Comment: The compiler usually works OK. No changes there. I am using tsc, in Terminal in VS Code.

Comment: how do you invoke it ? What is your commadn line ?if you pass in the files at the command line, the project file (ie tsconfig.json) is ignored

Comment: Try looking in 'tsconfig.app.json' file

Comment: It appears my problem was with using the outFile parameter. When I took this off, compiler worked - or - I had to specify the target in the command line, i.e. tsc --target es5 --outFile app.js circleMath.ts rectangleMath.ts app.ts